# How to Zoom out with tmap_mode "plot"

Tags: r, zooming, tmap

I created a world map using the code below. Right now, it shows the countries that have data. I want to be able to see zoomed out version of the world map in plot view. Insight on this issue will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
library(tmap)
tmap_mode("plot")
v7<-tm_shape(Omap)+
  tm_polygons("X", palette= "Reds",title="Country",
              colorNA="white",
              showNA=FALSE,
              border.alpha = 0)+
  tm_shape(worldmap2) +
  tm_borders(col = "grey",lwd = 0.5)+
  tm_layout(bg.color = "white")+
  tm_layout(frame = TRUE,outer.margins=c(.05,0,.05,0), inner.margins=c(0,0,.02,0), asp=0,
            legend.outside=FALSE,
            legend.position=c("right","bottom"),
             "Number", title.position = c('right','top'))+
  tm_legend(show=TRUE)+
  tm_view(set.view = c(lon = 0, lat = 0, zoom = 0))
#      legend.stack = "horizontal")
v7
```

Comment: if by "zooming out" you mean increasing the bounding box (adding some space around your plot) you may find this blog post helpful: https://www.jla-data.net/eng/adjusting-bounding-box-of-a-tmap-map/